# Does Viewbag return null?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

> I am getting error: Cannot perform runtime binding on null reference.
>
> Im getting the error trying to post back to my controll through an ajax call.

```js
$('#main-content-submit').click(function () {
        var labelArray = [];
        labelArray = $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).closest('label').text();
        }).get();
        console.log(labelArray);
        event.preventDefault();

        //Ajax call to get all months and years
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Extract',
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: labelArray}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (_result) {

            },
            error: function (err, _result) {
                alert("Error in Extract" + err.responseText);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



> Here is my view: I am getting the error and it is highlighting my @ViewBag.StatementYears items.
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="year" for="Year">Step 2 - Select Statement Year(s) :</label>

            <div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_1"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[0]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_2"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[1]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_3"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[2]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_4"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[3]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_5"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[4]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_6"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[5]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_7"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[6]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_8"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[7]</label>
                <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="type" id="chkBoxYear_9"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[8]</label>
            </div>
            <button id="selection" class="select-all-years">Select All Years</button>

        </div>
```

> Here is my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Extract(string[] name)
    {

        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your @ViewBag.StatementYears is defined?

Comment: Yes sir, so in my Index action in my homecontroller is where i am getting those years from. Everything works good until I add that ajax call. Could it be because I'm "post" it to a different action in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your **@ViewBag.StatementYears** is defined in **Index** controller, but not in **Extract** controller. You are trying to return a view without defining its ViewBag. I can suggest 2 solutions for you:

1. Define **@ViewBag.StatementYears** in **Extract** controller
2. Use `return RedirectToAction("Index")` instead of `return View("Index")` in your **Extract** controller.